# CTreeCtrl SelectItem is not selecting item

Tags: mfc, tree

I have 3 HTREEITEMs in MyCTreeCtrl tree control, a rootHti and two children, hti1 and hti2. I want to hightlight rootHti so I call myTreeCtrl.SelectItem(rootHti);. However, there is no change in the tree item. I also tried the long-hand way with the same results. That is, the item is not highlighted.

```
TVITEM item;
item.hItem = rootHti;
item.mask = TVIF_STATE;
item.state = TVIS_EXPANDED | TVIS_SELECTED;
item.stateMask = TVIS_EXPANDED | TVIS_SELECTED;
result = myTreeCtrl.SetItem(&item);
```

Is my assumption that selecting and highlighting incorrect? Clicking on the item highlights the item fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think rtischer8277's **highlighted** means it seems like mouse select a tree item.
So, when program start, 'root item' looks like below,

[image]

Without `TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS` style, even if `SelectItem()` is called, 'root item' will be different.

If I correct(I hope so), it is available by using **[TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760013.aspx)** style. Setting `TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS` is available by using `GetWindowLong() & SetWindowLong()`, as well as by using 'Properties' window of 'Tree Control'.

**EDIT**
Here is code which shows how to change the tree control style by using `GetWindowLong()`, `SetWindowLong()`.

```
CTreeCtrl* tree_ctrl = static_cast<CTreeCtrl*>(GetDlgItem(IDC_TREE1));

LONG tree_ctrl_style = GetWindowLongPtr(tree_ctrl->GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE);
if(!tree_ctrl_style)
{
    //FAIL
    AfxMessageBox(L"fail to get tree ctrl style");

    //GetLastError
    //

    return FALSE;
}

tree_ctrl_style |= TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS;

if(!SetWindowLongPtr(tree_ctrl->GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE, tree_ctrl_style))
{
    //FAIL
    AfxMessageBox(L"fail to set tree ctrl style");

    //GetLastError
    //

    return FALSE;
}

HTREEITEM root_item = tree_ctrl->InsertItem(L"Root");
tree_ctrl->InsertItem(L"Child1", 0, 0, root_item);
tree_ctrl->InsertItem(L"Child2", 0, 0, root_item);

tree_ctrl->SelectItem(root_item);
```

I used `GetWindowLongPtr(), SetWindowLongPtr()`, since [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/ms633584(v=vs.90).aspx) says,

> To write code that is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions
>   of Windows, use GetWindowLongPtr.

However, if your program is just sample or test, you don't care about that.

Comment: Setting the TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS style works. Since for this test I am using the resource editor, I set the appearance style property to Always Show Selection which sets the TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS flag.

Comment: There are at least two kinds of highlighting: shaded and mouse-clicked. Setting the TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS flag produces the shaded highlighting which looks like the root item in your screen shot.

Comment: I tried setting the style programmatically in my MFC app: '    long style = GetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
    style |= TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS;
    SetWindowLong(NULL, 0, style);', but it didn't work.

Comment: @rtischer8277 I've edited my answer. You maybe use `m_hWnd` of MainWindow, not `m_hWnd` of Tree Control. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Your code showed me that I had improperly set SetWindowLongPtr's nIndex parameter to 0 when it should have been GWL_STYLE.

Comment: @rtischer8277 So, is everything ok? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `TVIF_HANDLE` value to the `mask` field.

(and make sure `rootHti` is a valid Item Handle)

Comment: You should define "doesn't work". What is the value of `result` with and without `TVIF_HANDLE`?

Answer (score 0):

If calling

```
myTreeCtrl.SelectItem (rootHti);
```

works, then your handle is correct and you just need to add the handle flag to the mask as manuell suggests. I assume you're only doing it this way because you want the item expanded as well as selected, yes?

Comment: Yes, I only expanded because I wanted to see all the items. Adding the TVIF_HANDLE is not necessary and makes no change in the highlighted state.